# Error message is showing while adding or editing a product from dashboard

Tags: extensions, magento-2.1.3, third-party-module

I have installed a module from github Mageplaza_Seo. latter when i disabled it and when i went to dashboard and adding/editing products iam getting below error in /magento2/var/report log file

[image]

why this error occurring when my module is disabled too.and i have deleted folder from ftp

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mageplaza\Seo\Model\Source\Robots' not found in /home/shelltag/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always clear the cache after such change:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Depending on your compilation mode, you should have to execute:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

More info about [Magento compilation modes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html).

#### UPDATE

It looks like you have some attributes left after module uninstall. If you take a look at [InstallSchema.php](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-seo-extension/blob/master/Setup/InstallData.php), you'll notice that module is creating two attributes:

- mp_meta_robots for Products
- mp_meta_robots for Categories

Since those attributes are using `\Mageplaza\Seo\Model\Source\Robots` as source model, that's why you're seeing that error.

#### HOW TO FIX

For product attribute, you can go to the Magento Admin -> Stores -> Attributes -> Product. There you can find ***mp_meta_robots*** attribute, just click on it, and on the next screen choose ***Delete Attribute***.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to do it directly in database. The same thing you'll have to do for Categories, since there is no UI in Magento Admin for managing Category attributes.

This is SQL query you have to execute:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'mp_meta_robots';
```

Comment: my cache has been disabled already sir and i have disabled the module

Comment: What about `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`?

Comment: i have tried both sir setup:upgrade and setup:di:compile after deleting the module..do i need to delete table from database too??but iam unable to figure out the table??

Comment: still getting this error

Fatal error: Class 'Mageplaza\Seo\Model\Source\Robots' not found in /home/shelltag/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93

Comment: when iam adding or editing a product from dashboard than only iam getting that error..iam unable to figure it out from where its triggering

Comment: I've updated answer, it should be okay for you now.

Comment: sir but i cant see delete attributes when i go to dashboard-product-click on "mp_meta_robots" but cant see delete attribute option sir

Comment: cant i delete this product attribute from sql sir?and what would be the command for the same?

Comment: sir i managed to delete attibute is by going to attribute set and drag and drop mp_meta_robots..

Comment: You haven't solved the issue yet, you have to execute SQL query that I wrote above. You just ***masked*** issue at the moment. For example, if you try to save category, you may experience an exception too.

So, just execute the SQL query from above.

Comment: ok sir fine. i will run the query and inform

Comment: If it's good, just mark it as solution.